# I want to call parent function into function which is wraped in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Below is my code -

```
     contactNumberMask: function(value) {
       return value
     },

     componentDidMount: function() {
       this.params = {
          cellNumber: ''
       };
       var maskList =  $.masksSort($.masksLoad("http://cdn.rawgit.com/andr-04/inputmask-multi/master/data/phone-codes.json"), ['#'], /[0-9]|#/, "mask");
        this.maskOpts = {
          inputmask: {

             onMaskChange: function(maskObj, determined) {
                if (determined) {
                var number = this.contactNumberMask(maskObj.mask);
                this.params.cellNumber = number+'-'+this.params.cellNumber;
            }
        }
    };
},
```

In this i want to call this.contactNumberMask() function inside onMaskChange() function. but it is not getting reference of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context

```
        onMaskChange: function(maskObj, determined) {
            if (determined) {
            var number = this.contactNumberMask(maskObj.mask);
            this.params.cellNumber = number+'-'+this.params.cellNumber;
        }.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some ways to do. For example, storing the **this** reference in a variable.

```
 contactNumberMask: function(value) {},
 componentDidMount: function() {
   var that = this;
   this.params = {
      cellNumber: ''
   };
   var maskList =  $.masksSort($.masksLoad("http://cdn.rawgit.com/andr-04/inputmask-multi/master/data/phone-codes.json"), ['#'], /[0-9]|#/, "mask");
   this.maskOpts = {
     inputmask: {
       onMaskChange: function(maskObj, determined) {
         if (determined) {
           var number = that.contactNumberMask(maskObj.mask);
           this.params.cellNumber = number+'-'+this.params.cellNumber;
         }
       }
    };
 },
```

Comment: You missed the other `this` references before that line.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices :

- create a variable self at the beginning of componentDidMount function

  var self = this

Then you use self instead of this.

- you can also create a function _onMaskChange and then use the bind method to set the 'this' in this method

  onMaskChange: _onMaskChange.bind(this, maskObj, determined)

Answer (score 0):

Your `function(maskObj, determined)` block won't have the same context (`this`) as the surrounding block. That's because - if not specified other - a `function` block will create its own context (`this`). The function is not **bound** to the outer context.

Multiple answers above are an option. But what I would recommend is using the `=>` arrow function syntax. This will implicitly *bind()* your function to the outer context:

```
onMaskChange: (maskObj, determined) => {...}
```

Also it has a much cleaner syntax.

Comment: The arrow syntax is not available in all browsers, it can be an issue. But the arrow syntax don't bind the this sadly... It just don't create the this for the function so it looks like a binding but it is not... It's called a lexical this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: The would also recommend the use of an transpiler like babel, which nullifies most browser support headaches (and gives you the ability to use JS language features from `this` century).
But thanks for the clarification about the lexical `this`

Comment: Yes babel would help for sure ;) No worries I didn't know it yesterday either ahah!